# The main GUI freezes and counting stops while clicking the menu bar buttons

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

My problem is that when I click on the menu bar buttons, the counting in the main GUI window freezes until the the button is depressed. I have read a lot about threading and callback, after method but none of that helps to solve this problem. Unless I am missing something. Please let me know where the problem might be. Thanks!

```
from tkinter import*
import time
import _thread as thread

def NewFile():
    print ("New File!")
def OpenFile():
    showerror('Not implemented','Not yet available')
def About():
    print ("This is a simple example of a menu")

def my_func():

    for count in range(1000000):

        count = count + 1

        entry.delete(0,END)
        entry.insert(0, count)
        entry.update()  

def menu(root):             
    menu = Menu(root)
    root.config(menu=menu)
    filemenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
    filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=NewFile)
    filemenu.add_command(label="Open...", command=OpenFile)
    filemenu.add_separator()
    filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.destroy)
    helpmenu = Menu(menu)
    menu.add_cascade(label="Help", menu=helpmenu)
    helpmenu.add_command(label="About...", command=About)


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")


lab = Label(root, text="Date and Time", width=7, relief=SUNKEN, bg = "yellow", font = "times 16 bold")
lab.pack(side=TOP, fill=X,  padx=5, pady=5)
entry = (Entry(root, relief=SUNKEN, bg = "powder blue", fg="blue", justify='center', font = "times 16 bold"))
entry.insert(0,"0")
entry.pack(padx=5, pady=5)

root.after(20, my_func)
menu(root)  
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have imported threading but you are not using it anywhere...

Comment: I have tried to use them but it did not help it the way I understood it. So, I am stuck...

Comment: Do not use for loop in `my_func()`.  You can modify the `my_func()` to accept `count` as argument, update the `entry` and call `root.after(20, my_func, count+1)` inside `my_func()`.